# Unsure of output from Frobenius norm function

Tags: python, numpy

Define a function `f(x)` in that takes a matrix M as an input, and returns  `−||−0.5^2||` (the norm in question is the Frobenius norm, implemented by np.linalg.norm).

Print the result of a binary matrix of size 4x4.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x): #defines the function
    return -np.linalg.norm(M - np.dot(M,M)/2.) #returns the Frobenius norm

M = np.random.randint(2, size=[4,4]) #implementing random matrix
print(M) #printing random 2x2 matrix
print(f(x)) #printing f(x)
```

Note: I have added images to make it clear of my output.

My question that I have is I do not understand what the value: -1.9364916731037085 refers to.

Image of work:

[image: Whole image of work]

Output:

[image: Output image]

Comment: thank you - I typed the code and print screened it for clarity, I will bear this in mind thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> np.linalg.norm

is the Frobenius Norm. It is defined as below

[image]

It is square root of the sum of all the elements squared in the matrix

> np.dot(M,M)/2

is the dot product of M with itself divided by 2

```
-np.linalg.norm(M - np.dot(M,M)/2.)
```

Finally we are taking the Frobenius Norm of matrix which is result of (M - np.dot(M,M)/2.) which is a scalar and multiplying it with a -1. That is what you see when you run

> print(f(x))

```
M = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
n = np.dot(M,M)/2.
j = M - n
assert np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(j,2))) == np.linalg.norm(j)
```